# Name-dependent program behavior

Tags: c, windows, exe, sdl-2

I recently tried to write a C program with SDL2 for Windows 10. I use only one source file and SDL2 dll. The problem arises from the fact that if I change the name of the source file before compiling (or of the executable once compiled) instead of a 2000*1400 pixel window another huge one is created (see the photos).
[with the original name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSY9k.png) and
[with a diffent name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ47Z.png) (Each pixel is streched and the window goes to full screen)

I'm using MinGW as compiler with this syntax:

```
gcc -B "include path" "sourceName.c" -o "sourceName.exe" -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

This is the source:

```
#include <SDL2\SDL.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

SDL_Renderer* rend;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error initializing SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 0;
    }
    
    /* Create a window */
    SDL_Window* wind = SDL_CreateWindow("tst",
                                        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                        2000, 1400, 0);

    if (!wind)
    {
        printf("Error creating window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return 0;
    }

    /* Create a renderer */
    Uint32 render_flags = SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC;
    rend = SDL_CreateRenderer(wind, -1, render_flags);
    if (!rend)
    {
        printf("Error creating renderer: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_DestroyWindow(wind);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 0;
    }

    bool running = true;
    SDL_Event event;

    while (running)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    running = false;
            }
        }

        SDL_RenderPresent(rend);
    }
}
```

To summarize: if i change the name of the executable or of the source file (so if i'm working on another file) my window is completely streched.

Note that this doesn't happen with smaller dimensions such as 200*140 pixels.

I tried working in a completely different folder, reinstalling SDL and the compiler but nothing seems to work.

I can't figure out what the problem could be, could someone give me some advice?

Comment: What is resolution of your display? Maybe Windows remembers window dimensions previously set by user by process executable name?

Comment: Sounds like a highdpi issue to me. Maybe you have some settings associated with given name. What happens if you add `SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI` window flag?

Comment: @keltar thanks but nothing seems to change with that flag

Comment: @dimich How can i verify that? My resolution is 2256 X 1504. Thanks anyway